# Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I have hosted my MVC project hosted on a trial at somee.com
The email functionality is not working there. It works fine in my local system.
Raised a support ticket but have no response.

The error that is logged is :

```
ERROR TYPE : System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
ERROR MESSAGE : Failure sending mail.
INNER EXCEPTION MESSAGE : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

and the code is:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("myname@gmail.com", "My Name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("validemail@gmail.com", "");

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, SmtpPassword)
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = emailSubject,
                Body = emailBody,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            })
            {
                //turning the security off for testing
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                { return true; };
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
```

I have also hosted on Azure free subscription. It doesn't work there too. And logs the same error.

I wanted to test my site before making it live. Is this issue because it is a free/trial subscription.
Or
Should my code be changed to make it work when hosted on servers.